# How can i compare password with retypepassword during registering/creating account without having a field 'retyppassword' in models.py?

Tags: python, django, forms, templates, passwords

models.py:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='0')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    passwordrepeat = models.CharField('Repeat Password', max_length=300)
    password_token = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='0')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email_token = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email_token_expiry = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_action = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='0')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

class UsersModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'passwordrepeat', 'email')
        widgets = {
            'password' : PasswordInput(),
            'passwordrepeat' : PasswordInput(),
        }
```

views.py:

```
def register(request):
    flag = True
    possible = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    token = ''
    length = 10
    i = 0

    current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()

    user = UsersModelForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userf = UsersModelForm(request.POST)
        username = userf.data['username']
        password = userf.data['password']
        passwordrepeat = userf.data['passwordrepeat']
        email = userf.data['email']

        if password != passwordrepeat:
            flag = False
            passVariable = {'user':user, 'flag': False}
            return render_to_response('register.html', passVariable, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

        elif password == passwordrepeat:
            while i<10:
                temp = random.choice(possible)
                token = token + temp
                i=i+1

            userf.email_token = token
            userf.email_token_expiry = current_datetime + timedelta(1)
            userf.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('register.html', {"user": user, 'flag': True}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In template:

```
<div id="id_div_register">
    <form action="/register" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ user.as_p }}
        <input type=submit value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

This form creates a textbox 'repeatpassword' because of the field in models.py. I don't want to have a field 'repeatpassword' in the mysql table field/column. But i need to compare 'password' with 'repeatpassword' in template. How can i do it?

I need 'password' and 'repeatpassword' in template to compare these two, but i don't need a column/field 'repeatpassword' in blog_users mysql table. How can i do it? Is it possible to do it.

Comment: [Form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/validation/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your need a new field on the form which is cleaned to check the passwords match, then you can remove the password checks within your view and replace with [form.is_valid()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#processing-the-data-from-a-form). Something like the following:

```
class UsersModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    passwordrepeat = forms.PasswordInput()
    class Meta:
        model = Users

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        passwordrepeat = cleaned_data.get("passwordrepeat")
        if password != passwordrepeat:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must match.")

        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Where is `widgets` in models.py? can you post the complete models.py and views.py to understand easily what you are trying to say?

Comment: Is the indentation of return `cleaned_data` ok or is it outside the `def clean(self):`

Comment: When would i call the clean method?

Answer (score 13):

**YOU MUST NEVER NEVER NEVER DO THIS.**

You are storing user's passwords in clear in the database. **You must not do this**.

Django has a complete built-in authentication framework which takes care of all the security required to store passwords properly, including hashing. Use it. It is not complex, and in fact is much easier than rolling your own.

Get rid of your insecure version and use Django's.

Comment: I need option to register/create account first, then authentication.

Comment: How does that comment in any way relate to my answer? Don't create insecure systems for storing passwords. Use Django's. If you need to put a registration mechanism on top, use something like [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration).

Comment: Those django-registration or django-auth look complex to me. That's why i need make my own.

Comment: I'm sure your clients will be happy when you tell them they were hacked because you preferred slapping your own system together instead of taking the time to read the documentation about how to do it properly.

Comment: Why would other hack it? If i hash the password before saving, then would other be able to hack it?

Answer (score 2):

Remove passwordrepeat from model.
Extend UsersModelForm to passwordrepeat input.
Check do passwords match in UsersModelForm custom validation (is_valid() method)

Comment: Can't understand what you are saying, posting complete code will be helpful to understand. Can you post the code of models.py?

Comment: Why you're not using Django's user authentication mechanism: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth
and extend models.User by UserProfile (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) in a first place ?

Comment: models.py would be the same but delete `passwordrepeat = models.CharField('Repeat Password', max_length=300)` field.

Comment: Using those auth looks complex to me.